# Normalizer of Factors in an Amalgamated Free Product

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, free-product

I am reading through [this](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Free_factor_implies_self-normalizing_or_trivial) proof that if $H$ is a non-trivial group, then the normalizer of $H$ in the free product $G:=H \ast K$ is equals $H$ (i.e., is trivial). Most of the proof seems to generalize to amalgamated free products. There's just one possibly troublesome step at the very end. Basically, the proof goes as follows.

Assume by way of contradiction that $H$ is not self-normalizing, so there exists $g \in N_{G}(H) \setminus H$. Without loss of generality, assume the first and last letter of $g$ come from the $K$ factor. Now, choose *any* non-trivial element $h \in H$. Then $ghg^{-1}$ is also a reduced word of length greater than one, so $ghg^{-1} \notin H$, which contradicts the fact that $g$ normalizes $H$.

My question is:

> Does this fact generalize to amalgamated free products, or is there a nice class of examples where we have this? That is, if $H$ and $K$ are amalgamated over a group $A$ (not sure if that's the correct vernacular), is $H$ self-normalizing in $H \ast_{A} K$?

For my purposes, I don't really care $A$ and $K$ are (they can be fixed), but I would like $H$ to be more or less arbitrary (or as arbitrary as possible if that makes sense).

The fact that we can just choose *any* non-trivial $h \in H$ and we get the desired contradiction is interesting. If it's not generally true that $H$ is self-normalizing in $H \ast_{A} K$, is it possible there is a "nice" and not too restrictive class of $H$'s where we *can* show that $H$ is self-normalizing in $H \ast_{A} K$.

Comment: I think  essentially the same proof goes through (provided that $A$ is a proper subgroup of $H$ and of $K$). Elements outside of $A$ can be written as an alternating product of elements of $H \setminus K$ and $H \setminus H$ and the length of such an expression is determined by the element. You can assume the first and last letters of such an expression for $g$ lie in $K \setminus H$ and then choose your $h$ in $H \setminus K$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ah, very nice! That's not very restrictive at all! Is $H \setminus H$ a typo?

Comment: Yes, should be $K \setminus H$.

Comment: Please do not just create new tags.  If you believe that a new tag is needed, please use the [Tag Management thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35451/) to make a proposal.

Comment: Bass-Serre theory gives a nice view of this result: Every free product with amalgamation $H*_AK$ acts on a tree $T$, without inversion of edges, where edge stabilisers are conjugates of either $H$ or $K$, and edge stabilisers are conjugates of $A$. Adjacent vertices are conjugates of different factors. Once you have this construction, then your result follows immediately as normality of $H$ or $K$ means that the tree has at most two vertices so your action is trivial.

Comment: (typo: "where *vertex* stabilisers are conjugates of either $H$ or $K$".)

Comment: @user1729 But not being a normal subgroup does not mean that the normalizer is trivial, right? Maybe I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: @user193319 A non-normal subgroup can have non-trivial normaliser, for example, in $H\ast K$, a normal subgroup $N$ of $H$ will have normaliser $H$. (There are too many "nots" in your question, but I think I've interpreted it correctly!)

Comment: @user1729 But I don't want non-trivial normalizers. I want $H$ and $K$ to have trivial normalizer in the amalgamation (i.e., I want them to be self-normalizing). But, again, maybe I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: @user193319 Sorry, re-reading my comment I was assuming that $H$ or $K$ was normal, which I shouldn't have been doing. Instead, I should have been pointing out that the normaliser of $H$ fixes the same vertex as $H$, and so if $H$ is not self-normalising we have that $H=A$, and so $G=K$.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Derek Holt, you just have to be a bit more careful because the "normal form" for $H*_AK$ is different.

A common way of defining the normal form is the following: pick a set of left coset representatives $\{h_i\}_{i\in I}$ for $A$ in $H$, with $e_H$ the representative of $H$; and a set of left coset representatives $\{k_j\}_{j\in J}$ for $A$ in $K$, with the representative of $A$ being $1_K$.

Then the elements of $H*_AK$ have can be expressed uniquely in the form
$$h_{i_1}k_{i_1}\cdots h_{i_r}k_{i_r}a$$
where $a\in A$, and none of the $h_{i_s}$ or $k_{j_t}$ are equal to $1$, except perhaps for $h_{i_1}$ and/or $k_{i_r}$.

To explain how to multiply two such elements let's consider the case of an element of the form $h_{i_1}k_{j_1}a$ times an element of the form $k_{j_2}h_{i_3}k_{j_3}a'$. Write out the element:
$$h_{i_1}k_{j_1}ak_{j_2}h_{i_3}k_{j_3}a'.$$
Now we shift $a$ to the "end". The element $k_{j_1}ak_{j_2}$ lies in $K$, so it can be written uniquely as $k_{u_1}a_1$ for some $u_1\in J$, $a_1\in A$. This gives
$$h_{i_1}k_{u_1}a_1h_{i_3}k_{j_3}a'.$$
If $k_{u_1}$ is not trivial, then rewrite $a_1h_{i_3}$ as $h_{v_1}a_2$ and replace it in the expression. If $k_{u_1}=1$, then rewrite $h_{i_1}a_1h_{i_3}$ in the form $h_{v_1}a_2$ and replace it in the expression. Etc. Continue this way until the $a$ has been "shifted" all the way to the right, and left of it you have an alternating list of coset representatives in $H$ and in $K$.

Then in the final part of your argument you can take any $h\in H$, and an element $x$ not in $H$. Assuming it normalizes $H$, you can assume that it has the form $k_{j_1}\cdots h_{i_r}k_{j_r}$ (by left and right multiplying by an element of $H$, which certainly normalizes), and $k_{j_1},k_{j_r}\neq 1$, and write $h=h_ua$. Then $xhx^{-1}$ will have normal form that starts with $k_{j_1}$ and so does not lie in $H$.